# Best way to generate a 2 char alphanumeric string?

Tags: php

what is the fastest way to generate a random two long alphanumeric character?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Check out my answer for a elegant way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do the job beautifully:

```
substr(md5(uniqid(microtime(true),true)),0,2);
```

This technique is used quite often for alphanumeric password salts in databases.

Comment: Artelius has a valid point. I'm not sure if that's an issue for your application or not, though.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Jani's answer:

```
join('', array_rand(array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('0', '9')), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$az = range('a', 'z');
$r = array_rand($az, 2);
$str = $az[$r[0]] . $az[$r[1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
base_convert(rand(0,35), 10, 36) . base_convert(rand(0,35), 10, 36)
```